# Organizing JPanels and Layouts

Tags: java, swing, layout, border-layout

So I have the following screen:

[image: Screen]

And this is my code:

```
setLayout(new BorderLayout());

JLabel lblTitulo = new JLabel("Sistema Generador de Examenes");     
lblTitulo.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 18));

JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
panel1.setBackground(Color.white);
panel1.add(lblTitulo);
add(panel1, BorderLayout.NORTH);

JButton btnCrear = new JButton("Crear Examen");
JButton btnRendir = new JButton("Rendir Examen");
JButton btnCorregir = new JButton("Corregir Examen");
JButton btnVerCorrecciones = new JButton("Ver Correcciones");

btnCrear.setBounds(15, 100, 450, 35);
btnRendir.setBounds(15, 150, 450, 35);
btnCorregir.setBounds(15, 200, 450, 35);
btnVerCorrecciones.setBounds(15, 250, 450, 35);

JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
panel2.setBackground(Color.white);
panel2.setLayout(null);
panel2.add(btnCrear);
panel2.add(btnRendir);
panel2.add(btnCorregir);
panel2.add(btnVerCorrecciones);

add(panel2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

1 - I'm using the BorderLayout. Do I need to have 2 JPanels to separate components (JLabel and JButtons) if I want to have the JLabel in the North and the JButtons in the Center? Or is there any way to use just one JPanel?

2 - I want to take out the setBounds used in my JButtons and use some Layout in order to have my JButtons like that in the middle of the screen. How could I do that?

Comment: Nest JPanels, each using their own layouts and you can easily achieve this. The layout manager tutorial will show you what each layout can do. For my money, I try to avoid using GridBagLayout or GroupLayout and instead nest several of the simpler and easier to use layouts.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm using the BorderLayout. Do I need to have 2 JPanels to separate components (JLabel and JButtons) if I want to have the JLabel in the North and the JButtons in the Center? Or is there any way to use just one JPanel?

Yes, you could use one JPanel and a GridBagLayout with a single column and some Insets to space the buttons from the label.

However, the nested layouts will keep the buttons in the center no matter how you resize the JFrame.

> I want to take out the setBounds used in my JButtons and use some Layout in order to have my JButtons like that in the middle of the screen. How could I do that?

The GridBagLayout will space out the buttons with insets.

See this article, [Sudoku Solver Swing GUI](http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=196), for a couple of examples of dialogs that use the GridbagLayout.